# ruby on rails: print plain text from web app to my locale printer directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, printers, thermal-printer

I claim that I searched for weeks without found an answer.

I'm developing a web app in rails located in a web server and I need to print some text to my home thermal printer. I want to do this directly without open browser dialog and the app should do this on all the browser.

I know that I can do it with **Google Cloud Print** but it will only works with Chrome. ( I can add this printer only in **classic printer** mode, because Cloud Print does not support it as cloud printer ).

There is a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean print on the users printer without a dialog this will not be possible for security reasons. If you want to print on a printer you own then you would need some web service which the browser can talk to, the web service could communicate with the locally attached printer. So basically you are going to want to run your Rails app on the same computer as the printer.

Comment: @Kris Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: To add to this...and though I'm late to the party here...one could also potentially setup a raspberry pi with an api service that you can send to, with the data to trigger the local print...and yes, these sorts of printers can only usually be setup as generic due to the commands and content being character based.